# Change/edit text of whiptail gauge

Tags: bash, whiptail, progress-information

I know that I can change the progress of a whiptail --gauge using something like:

```
{
    for ((i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i+=20)); do
        sleep 1
        echo $i
    done
} | whiptail --gauge "Please wait while installing" 6 60 0
```

But I am wondering whether it is possible to edit/modify the text of the whiptail box (so change the `Please wait while installing` text to something else.

My current solution is to bring up a new whiptail box, but there is a noticeable flicker between the old one closing and the new one opening. If you can't update the text of a whiptail box, is it possible to reduce/remove this flicker instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

msgs=( "Downloading" "Verifying" "Unpacking" "Almost Done" "Done" )

for i in {1..5}; do
  sleep 1
  echo XXX
  echo $(( i * 20 ))
  echo ${msgs[i-1]}
  echo XXX
done |whiptail --gauge "Please wait while installing" 6 60 0
```

Comment: Geez, how did I miss that?

Answer (score 1):

The flicker comes from (a) switching to/from the alternate/normal screens in the terminal and (b) from clearing the display.

You can eliminate the first part by choosing a terminal description lacking the control sequences used for switching between normal/alternate screens.  Usually those are the `smcup` and `rmcup` capabilities in the terminal description, so...

```
infocmp >foo
vi
...remove the assignments to `rmcup` and `smcup`
tic foo
...with ncurses, that likely creates an entry in `$HOME/.terminfo`
```

`dialog` handles this by optionally suppressing those capabilities (i.e., `--keep-tite`); `whiptail` doesn't know anything about the alternate screen.

Further reading:

- [dialog - display dialog boxes from shell scripts](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html)
- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)